# Android (Scaled) ImageView with Overlay and ListView

Tags: android, imageview, overlay, scaling

I am trying to place a "play" button on top of images that represent videos. I was hoping that Android supported this sort of overlay or glyph technique directly, but I couldn't find any way to do it.

(Note these images are scaled at various sizes using bitmaps).

I've tried several approaches including using LayerDrawable (one for the image, one for the overlay), using a FrameLayout and setting the foreground to the overlay and finally, extending ImageView and drawing the overlay after the image has been scaled and rendered.

I found with the first two approaches, the overlay itself was being scaled along with the image which is unacceptable. I simply want to place the overlay, as is, over the scaled image center.

Here's the code I'm using in the extension to ImageView:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if (overlayBitmap == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (getDrawable() == null) {
        return; 
    }

    if (getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth() == 0 
            || getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight() == 0) {
        return; 
    }

    int w = getMeasuredWidth();
    int h = getMeasuredHeight();

    // Determine the post-scaled size of the overlay
    r.set(0, 0, overlayBitmap.getWidth(), overlayBitmap.getHeight());
    matrix.mapRect(r);
    // Move the overlay to the center
    matrix.postTranslate(w / 2 - r.width() / 2, h / 2 - r.height() / 2);

    // Draw the overlay
    canvas.drawBitmap(overlayBitmap, matrix, paint);

}
```

This seems to work well in all cases but one. These images start their lives in a ListView. When selected, they move to a display area and the "play" button is there and is stable. However, while in the ListView, the images are unstable.Sometimes the overlay is there and sometimes not. Sometimes the overlay is in the center and sometimes not. All in all the overlays are mostly missing or wrong.

It looks to me as though this is some sort of (rectangle) invalidation issue (just a wild guess). That is, the ImageView subclass onDraw (where the overlay is drawn) is not called when scroll repainting occurs.

Now of course this could also be a bug in my program of course, but the code that manipulates the ImageVew subclass and sets the overlay are very well contained.

Any ideas?

**EDIT** I just found ViewOverlay which looks promising **BUT** I must support Ice Cream Sandwich (or minimally Jelly Bean 1) and this API requires Jelly Bean 3 (4.3) I don't even own a Jelly Bean 3 compatible tablet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest replacing

```
    int w = getMeasuredWidth();
    int h = getMeasuredHeight();
```

with:

```
     int x = canvas.getWidth();
     int y = canvas.getHeight();
```

Because getMeasuredWidth() and getMeasuredHeight() results are masked and do something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
     ....
     ....
        Bitmap play = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.play);
     int width = play.getWidth();
     int height = play.getHeight();
     int x = canvas.getWidth()/2 - width/2;
     int y = canvas.getHeight()/2 - height/2;
    canvas.drawBitmap(play, x, y, new Paint());
    }
```

No matter how much I scale the image, the play button stays in center on top of image

Comment: Thank you so much. Works perfectly. Apart from incorrect positioning using the measured size, it was the Matrix transform that was causing the instability. I should not have messed with Matrix transform coding, when I really don't know what I'm doing!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a framelayout with two children..first is the imageview with your scaled image , wrap/wrap. Second is a text view or view with its background set to your overlay image and match/match for layout params

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I went with @Wildroid solution below because I could reuse the code I had and I'm lazy :-). Much appreciated.